# Inconsistent unboxing technique in java

Tags: java, autoboxing

Below code,

```
package AutoBoxing;

/*
 * When a wrapper type is initialized do you get a new object created?
 * Answer: It depends!!!!
 * 1) If you use a constructor then a new instance will be created.
 * 2) If you use boxing('Integer i = 127'), and the value being boxed is a 
 * boolean, byte, char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, int or short in the 
 * range -128 to 127 then there is a single object. Technical phrase is 'interned'  
 */
public class Example2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = 127, j = 127;
        Integer k = new Integer(127);
        System.out.println(i == j); // unboxed values are compared
        System.out.println(i == k); // memory addresses are compared

    }

}
```

gives

```
true
false
```

as output.

`true` because objects are unboxed and values are compared(`127 == 127`).

`false` because memory addresses are compared.

Why unboxing is not done in second case? Because `k`is also of type wrapper class to primitive?

Comment: "true because objects are unboxed and values are compared" - nope, that's not what's happening here.

Comment: @JonSkeet  memory addresses are compared in first case as well?

Comment: Yes. read the duplicate question.

Comment: There is no unboxing involved in the first comparison. It is just that when you do `Integer i = 127;`, it's compiled into `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(127);` and hence fetch the instance from the cache (the class has a cache of instances by default from -128 to 127), thus they are the same instances.

Try with 

    `Integer i = 128, j = 128;
    Integer k = new Integer(128);`

and you see that it'll output:

    `false
    false`